# GeoServer custom configuration is overidden being overridden by EFS in AWS ECS deployment

Tags: geoserver, amazon-web-services, docker, configuration

We're using Amazon ECS to deploy our custom GeoServer Docker image and have opted to mount an Amazon EFS filesystem for the GeoServer data directory. Within this directory on EFS, we have several data directories, and we've made specific customizations to the **global.xml** and the **config.xml** located inside the **security** folder.

However, when we start our ECS cluster using this EFS configuration, the modifications made to the **global.xml** and **config.xml** files are overridden, reverting them to what seems like the default configurations. This behavior is unexpected and inconsistent with our local setups where the modifications remain intact.

We're seeking guidance on how to ensure our custom configurations within these **XML files** are preserved in the ECS environment while still leveraging EFS for the GeoServer data directory. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: turn logging up to GeoTools Dev and see what the log says when you start up